# Could not able to provide requirement.txt in paperboy?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, airflow, job-scheduling

I have installed paperboy from:

```
https://github.com/timkpaine/paperboy
```

I am trying to execute notebook with dependancy in **requirement.txt**

I have executed paperboy using

```
python -m paperboy.server --backend='sqla' --auth='sqla' --scheduler='airflow'
```

my requirement file:

```
cv
```

while executing its throwing error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-91a2ffa00be2> in <module>
----> 1 import cv

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv'
```

As per paperboy source code, there is a function **create_virtualenv** uses **requirements.txt** file and create a virtual environment.

But this function has never been called.

Do anyone knows how to fix this?

Thank you...!

Comment: ```cv``` means? Do you mean by openCV?

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav I just picked a random library (i.e. cv). And my notebook has only one line code (import cv). Even if I try for another library and try to import it's showing the same error.

Comment: First install package named ```openCV``` using ```pip install openCV```. And then type ```import cv``` or ```import cv2```

Comment: Hello @VaibhavJadhav, thanks for your response. This is not a problem with the cv library. Because I have tried it with other libraries (i.e. numpy, camelcase). Still facing same issue